# THREE.js pausing animation when not in use

Tags: javascript, three.js, requestanimationframe

I'm building my THREE.js app with React and I have two components, a carousel scene made in THREE.js and a full-screen overlay scene. When the overlay is displayed, I want to pause the carousel scene since it's not visible at all.

Currently, I'm just canceling the animation frame with `window.cancelAnimationFrame` but I'm noticing on a couple snippets online that people tend to just set a variable like `stop` to `true` and then inside the `update` loop, it would be something like:

```
update() {
  if (this.stop)
  this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
}
```

I was wondering if one of them had better performance than the other? Like if canceling & restarting an animation frame was more expensive than just keeping the animation loop going.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, using `cancelAnimationFrame` will have better performance because your processor won't have to execute the function and check for `this.stop` 60 times per second. However, modern day processors are so powerful, that running a simple `if()` statement is insignificant, and your performance difference is going to be minuscule.

Both options solve your problem, so giving you an answer is more of a matter of opinion, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.